# Bash - why I can execute command string with pipelines only through "bash -c"?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

Code example below shows the problem:

```
bash -c "$(echo 'ls | wc -l')" # Working
"$(echo 'ls | wc -l')"         # Not working
$(echo 'ls | wc -l')           # Not working
'ls | wc -l'                   # Not working
'ls'                           # Working
ls | wc -l                     # Obviously working
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give the shell a text string to execute, it will be able to do so if it happens to correspond to a command, like `"ls"` (`"ls -l"` is not the name of a command).

- Your first example works because the `echo` in the command execution is executed by the invoking shell, generating `bash -c "ls | wc -l"`.  The pipeline is then executed by `bash -c`, which is fine.
- The second, third and fourth example doesn't work since an extra step of evaluation needs to happen on the generated text string `ls | wc -l`. `eval` would do this for you.

The reason `"ls -l"` or `"ls | wc -l"` does not work is that quote removal happens *after* word splitting in the evaluation of the command line.

The reason `$(echo 'ls | wc -l')` doesn't work is that command substitution also happens after word splitting.

Comment: So, executing such string through bash/sh/zsh/whatever is the only available option?

Comment: @DenisSheremet No, your could also use the built-in command `eval`. I did mentioned this.  `eval "ls | wc -l"`.